# What happens when a subclass object is passed to a method with a superclass parameter?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to pass a subclass object to a method that has a superclass parameter so I only have to make one of that method. I have conditional statements like "if (subclassObject instanceOf CertainSubClass)" so it can tell which subclass the object came from.

The problem is once the object is passed to the parameter the program seems to only recognize it as a superclass object. Then I can't add it to an ArrayList of the type `ArrayList<CertainSubClass>`.

What exactly happens to the subclass object when it's passed to a method with a superclass parameter? And how could I get around this problem? I'd rather not make 3 methods for the 3 subclasses I have. Thanks

Comment: Could you add some sample code ?

Comment: Please add some code and format the question properly

Comment: If you pass in a `subclassObject` it will return `true` for the instanceof check, no matter what the local parameter's declared type is. The error should be somewhere else. Also, using `instanceof` is usually a bad design smell. Ideally, it is not necessary to inspect the runtime class.

Comment: If you want to add to a `ArrayList<CertainSubClass>` you will have to have an intermediate typecast to a local variable. Otherwise it won't compile. (Are you getting compile-time errors or runtime errors?)

Answer (score 1):

"I'd rather not make 3 methods for the 3 subclasses I have."

But if your process is different for each case (and your instanceof checks will make it so) then you *HAVE* 3 distinct methods, semantically.  Bundling them in one method just for the purpose of saving some method declarations is a poor idea.

Comment: This exactly. Create the 3 methods and refactor the shared parts of code (for example your initializations or calculations) to a helper method which all 3 main methods can call. This centralizes the shared code and keeps the rest clean and clear.